# Redirection sends me to the same page when I press "Back"

Tags: browser, website, web, webpage

On some websites, when you hit the "Back" button, the browser attempts to go to the previous web page, but the current page opens up again. It happens even when the original page has finished loading. Hitting the "Back" button dozens of times doesn't prevent the behaviour, and I get "stuck" on that page.

What would explain this? It has happened to me on virtually every browser I've ever used.

Answer (score 9):

You're probably hitting an 'in-between' redirection page, generally they are a blank page designed to load fast enough that you barely noticed they have done anything. These pages are often used when submitting forms or when the website is logging how and when you left the previous page without needing a form submitted.

You can read about some of the different reasons [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).

If you click and hold the back button (on most browsers) it will give you a list of pages from that particular tab that you can go back to. Chances are the page you're looking for is second on the list.

Comment: There was a time when internet was so slow that we could actually see these blank redirection pages in between...

Comment: @Michael What did you mean by 'in-between' redirection page. Can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: I hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Sorry didn't get your point. Have you edited your answer?

Comment: On Internet Explorer (at least some versions), there is a menu with the “Back” and “Forward” buttons that lets you jumps multiple pages – [here’s what it looks like in IE 8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4FGkB.png). ISTR that earlier versions had separate “Back” and “Forward” menus.